# Initializing Generic Variables in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble working with generics. I have a method as

```
    public void push (T element)
```

Now what I'm having trouble understanding is how to create a generic variable so that I can pass it into that method. I know that the generic will always be a number, but I'm not getting how I should do that. Would it have to be something like

```
T number = 5
```

And then would I be able to pass that into the push method? I'm quite confused. Thoughts guys?

Comment: Oracle has a decent tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: How about `Integer number = 5;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that T was a Number

```
public class NumberStack<T extends Number> {
   public void push(T element) {
     // now you can add Number specific functionality here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You aren't working with a generic variable persay.  Your code would look like this:

```
public class Stack<T> {
   public void push(T element) {
   }
}
```

When you go to initialize Stack you provide the type:

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
stack.push("hello");
```

Whatever you initialize the type for the class is the type of variable you pass to your method.