# How to initialize an abstract Number to 0?

Tags: java, templates, initialization

I would like to initialize a variable which is extended the Number class. My test :

```
class IgniteReducer<T extends Number> {

    private T sum = (Number) 0; // Here I have the problem

    public boolean collect(T number) {
        sum += number;
        return true;
    }

    public T reduce() {
        return sum;
    }

}
```

Anybody have an idea how to solve this initialization ?

Comment: When `T extends Number`, why do you cast here `T sum = (Number) 0`?

Comment: its already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340383/initializing-generic-variables-in-java

Comment: What are you trying to do? These are the subclasses of `Number` in the standard library, and "+" is not defined on any of them: AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, DoubleAccumulator, DoubleAdder, Float, Integer, Long, LongAccumulator, LongAdder, Short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do that. There is no generic way to set a `Number` to 0. As Joni said in a comment, there also is no generic way of adding two instances of the same subclass of `Number`.

One option is to defer those two operations to a subclass that knows the concrete type that `T` represents. So your main class will have to be abstract.

```
abstract class IgniteReducer<T extends Number> {

    protected T sum = zero();

    protected abstract T zero();

    public abstract boolean collect(T number);

    public T reduce() {
        return sum;
    }

}
```

One concrete implementation could be:

```
class IgniteFloatReducer extend IgniteReducer<Float> {

    Float zero() {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean collect(Float number) {
        sum += number;
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have typed the code here without testing it, so please forgive any typo.